# SPARQL Query: How I get only a literal or string as result?

Tags: rdf, sparql

**Data:**

```
<untitled-ontology-5:OperationName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
  Adhesive Curing
</untitled-ontology-5:OperationName>
```

**SPARQL Query:**

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://wwww.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/7/9/untitled-ontology-5#>
SELECT ?object
WHERE { ?subject  rdf:OperationName ?object .       
}
```

**Result:**

```
Adhesive Curing^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
```

---

**My Question:**

The result of the SPARQL Query is not the result what I wanted. The right result should contain only the Literal/String without the URI-part. I'd like to create the following result:

**Proper Result:**

```
Adhesive Curing
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use the `STR()` function to retrieve the lexical label of your literal:

Query:

```
SELECT (str(?object) as ?label) 
WHERE { ?subject rdf:OperationName ?object . }
```