# Print dateTime without specifying datatype in Sparql output

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, ontology

I am using following sparql Query in Jena to print some information:

```
   String qr = "PREFIX : <http://www.example.com/tempsensor#>\n" +
               "PREFIX  xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> \n"+
                 "SELECT \n"+
                "?Place ?Temperature ?Date \n"+ 
                 "WHERE\n"+
                "{ ?ind :locatedIn ?Place .\n " +
                  "?ind :measures ?Temperature .\n " +
                  "?ind :onDate ?Date .\n " +
                "FILTER(regex(str(?Place),'Delhi', 'i'))\n"+
                "FILTER ( datatype(?Date) = xsd:dateTime)\n"+
                "}";
```

Output obtained is:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------
| Place  | Temperature | Date                                |
==============================================================
| :Delhi | 16          | "2014-10-02T03:20:10"^^xsd:dateTime |
```

But, I don't want the datatype attached in Date Column. I need output like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Place  | Temperature | Date                                |
==============================================================
| :Delhi | 16          | 2014-10-02T03:20:10                 |
```

How shold I specify this in query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SPARQL Query: How I get only a literal or string as result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724868/sparql-query-how-i-get-only-a-literal-or-string-as-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a project expression to just get the string form of the literal:

```
String qr = "PREFIX : <http://www.example.com/tempsensor#>\n" +
            "PREFIX  xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> \n"+
            "SELECT \n"+
            "?Place ?Temperature (STR(?Date) AS ?StrDate) \n"+ 
            "WHERE\n"+
            "{ ?ind :locatedIn ?Place .\n " +
            "  ?ind :measures ?Temperature .\n " +
            "  ?ind :onDate ?Date .\n " +
            "  FILTER(regex(str(?Place),'Delhi', 'i'))\n"+
            "  FILTER ( datatype(?Date) = xsd:dateTime)\n"+
            "}";
```

Here we use the built-in [STR()](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) function to convert the value of `?Date` to just its string form without the data type.

SPARQL defines a wide range of built-in functions which it is well worth your time reading up on - http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#expressions