# sparql - How to remove Xml from query result

Tags: sparql

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX base: <http://www.cs7is1.com/ireland-school-county#>

SELECT ((COUNT(?school))/?a AS ?density) 
WHERE {
 ?school base:inCounty base:DUBLIN.
  base:area ?a
}
GROUP BY ?a
```

I run this query, query is fine but I am getting a result like this

```
"0.47776812"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>
```

I want to remove the XML content, I tried to bind it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPARQL Query: How I get only a literal or string as result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724868/sparql-query-how-i-get-only-a-literal-or-string-as-result)

Comment: That's not XML content. Your result is a typed literal, which happens to be an `xsd:float`; that part you're thinking of as XML is the type. You can cast the result as a string literal (as `SELECT (xsd:string((COUNT(?school))/?a) AS ?density)`) which *may* be implicitly typed, but also *may* be explicitly typed, depending on the engine you're running against. The other comment points to another possibility.